# Have any Doctor Who books been referenced explicitly in the series?

Tags: doctor-who, novel

In all the years of Doctor Who being on the air, has any story, character, plot arc, or reference been made that originated in one of the Doctor Who novels?

Comment: _Human Nature/Family of Blood_ was a novel first, before it became a TV episode. Does that count?

Comment: I believe that it is written into the terms of the TV series that (paraphrasing) that viewers must be able to fully enjoy the TV series without having read any books or works other than the TV series.  Presumably that's to prevent writers cross-promoting books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this has happened only once, and it was a complete off-hand comment that had no impact on the rest of the episode.

In the episode "Boom Town", Rose mentions having previously been to the Justica system. This trip occurred in a novel called *The Monsters Inside*, which also about the Slitheen. The novel was published approximately a month before the episode aired.

This is one of the few novels I've actually read, mostly because of this connection; the acknowledgements in the book make it clear that Russel T Davies approved the plot of the book, and thus the reference to Justica in the TV episode was most likely intentional.

(The novel also introduces a new race, the Blathereen, that are related to the Slitheen, which appear a few times in the *Sarah Jane Adventures* but not in any *Doctor Who* episodes.)

UPDATE:

Wikipedia also indicates that Martha Jones appeared in a novella *Made of Steel*, prior to her first on-screen appearance. I haven't read this one but it apparently includes the factoid that Torchwood scientist Adeola Oshodi (played by Freema) was Martha's cousin, something that Martha also mentions in "Smith and Jones". The novella appears to happen much later in Martha's timeline, however, so I don't know if this qualifies as a "reference to a novel" as much as the novel just being published way ahead of time.